# Cannot load Coredata module

Tags: xcode

I just created a fresh project to practice coredata and I'm getting this error. Thanks[image]

Answer (score 1):

The namespace of you `Coredata` project enters in conflict with the Apple `CoreData` framework. Change the name of your project to be able to compile